# How to put a shadow around each row with different sizes?

Tags: css

I have a table that appears to have rows with different sizes. I would like to place a shadow `box-shadow: 0 0 13px black` around each blue border.

[image: without shadow]

Simply putting the shadow on `tr` obviously doesn't do it:

[image: with shadow]

I have tried to play with the shadow on `td` but without success, mostly because the shadow bleeds between cells.

Any ways to do that?

My code below.

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="A">
            <td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td><td>A4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="B">
            <td></td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td><td>B4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="C">
            <td></td><td></td><td>C3</td><td>C4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="D">
            <td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td><td>D4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 20px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
tr {
    height: 40px;
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 13px black; */
}
td {
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
td:last-child {
    border-right: 2px solid blue;
}

.A td:nth-child(1) {border-left: 2px solid blue;}

.B td:nth-child(1) {border: none;}
.B td:nth-child(2) {border-left: 2px solid blue;}

.C td:nth-child(1) {border: none;}
.C td:nth-child(2) {border: none;}
.C td:nth-child(3) {border-left: 2px solid blue;}

.D td:nth-child(1) {border-left: 2px solid blue;}
```

Comment: Is using a `table` a specific requirement? Because I imagine you can achieve a similar result with either CSS grid or flexbox.

Comment: Yes, using table is required to take advantage of automatic table layout algorithm for calculating widths for columns. I wouldn't have that with grid/flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the CSS filter property on the tr element to make shadows as you wanted.

[CSS shadow on tr element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns1ws.jpg)

```
tr {filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222222);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure you can't do it without javascript because you need extra element between rows. You can do it like this:

```js
$("tr").each(function() {
  $("<div class='clearfix'></div>").insertBefore(this);
})
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
  content: '.'; 
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
table {
  border:2px solid #0f0;
  padding:0 10px;
}
table tr {
  float:right;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  margin:10px 0;
}
table td {
  width:100px; 
  text-align:center;
  border:2px solid #f00;
}
table td:empty {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="A">
            <td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td><td>A4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="B">
            <td></td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td><td>B4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="C">
            <td></td><td></td><td>C3</td><td>C4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="D">
            <td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td><td>D4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for me, `div` is not allowed as a child of `tbody`.